# Can not make websocket connection with Amber or NPM not sure which

Tags: javascript, npm, websocket, crystal-lang, amber-framework

Amber CLI (amberframework.org) - v0.11.3
Crystal 0.27.0 [c9d1eef8f] (2018-11-01)
LLVM: 4.0.0
Default target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
npm 3.5.2

I am trying to implement sockets with Crystal Lang and Amber. I followed the instructions from the [Amber Docs](https://docs.amberframework.org/amber/guides/websockets/javascript-client) and [Github Amber Readme.](https://github.com/amberframework/docs/blob/master/guides/websockets/javascript-client.md) However, I am receiving an error.

I am running "npm run watch" and "amber watch". I can see the web browser refresh when I make changes to main.js.

```
//main.js
import 'bootstrap';
import $ from 'jquery';
import Amber from 'amber';

let socket = new Amber.Socket('/notification')
socket.connect().then(function() {
  let channel = socket.channel('chat_room:hello');

  channel.join();

  channel.push('message_new', {
    message: "Hello Amber from WebSocket Client!"
  });

  channel.on('message_new', function(payload) {
    console.log(payload);
  });
});
// Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Socket' of undefined
// at Module../src/assets/javascripts/main.js (main.js:28)
// at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
// at Module../config/webpack/entry.js (entry.js:1)
// at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
// at bootstrap:83
// at bootstrap:83
```

UPDATE:

After inspecting the sources I noticed that there are 2 versions of main.js. The version throwing the error is located in "webpack://.src/assets/javascripts/main.js". When I inspect this file during run-time Amber can not be found. "ReferenceError: amber is not defined" The second version of the file is located in "/dist/main.bundle.js". I am not sure why both assets are being served. Is this possibly an issue with npm?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find an answer on the [Amber Forums](https://forum.crystal-lang.org/t/amber-npm-not-serving-assets-correctly/342). It would seem the default functionality was accidentally broken during a commit and a pr has been made. I am copying jackturnbull's answer here.

Solution 1, change the Amber import line to:

```
import * as Amber from 'amber';
```

Solution 2:

```
import { Channel, Socket } from 'amber';

// Then reference as:
let socket = new Socket('/notification');
...
```